# How do I ask Pandas to search for the specific amount of a data (eg. number of houses with the data NEAR BAY)?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I was trying to look for the amount of houses with the 5 types of data in ocean proximity (NEAR BAY, <1HR OCEAN, INLAND, NEAR OCEAN, ISLAND). The problem is I couldn't figure on how to make it work.

I tried using a code to count the amount of houses with NEAR BAY, 1HR OCEAN, INLAND, NEAR OCEAN, and ISLAND attached to the excel file. Here is the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

proximities = []

for i in range(20640):
  if not data.ocean_proximity[i] in proximities:
    proximities.append(data.ocean_proximity[i])
proximities

df = pd.DataFrame(data.ocean_proximity)
print(df.count())
```

And here is the result:

```
ocean_proximity    20640
dtype: int64
```

And this is the result I was expecting (note the numbers are just random, the numbers can be completely different in the result):

```
NEAR BAY       927
<1HR OCEAN     2284
INLAND         2060
NEAR OCEAN     9482
ISLAND         4133
```

So is there any way to be able to make the code work like this, or is Google Colab bugged?

By the way, here is the Excel file used:
file:///C:/Users/Minerva%20Panganiban/Downloads/housing.pdf

Comment: `data['ocean_proximity'].value_counts()`

Comment: Your first loop is highly inefficient (and useless). If you want the unique values `proximities = data['ocean_proximity'].unique()`